# best way to replace text in string with java

Tags: java, string, excel, replace, filenames

I have a problem.

I have about **10,000** `.Xls` files. they are named `000001.xls`, `000002.xls ...`

My code looks something like this:

```
File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
Workbook w;
String fileName = inputWorkbook.getName().replace("0", "");
```

The problem is when it replaces the `0` in `0000160.xls`, and it turns out `16.xls`, just like `0000016.xls` does.

I want it to be `160.xls`

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do actually ?!

Comment: Well, if that behaviour is wrong, then what is it that you ARE trying to do? It's hard to tell from what you've posted so far.

Comment: Okey, 0000016.xls and 0000160.xl both turn out 16.xls when i replace 0. I want 0000160.xls to be named 160.xls

Comment: Use Integer.ValueOf(filename) and add extention .xls

Comment: and don't pass .xls to valueOf fuction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String fileName = inputWorkbook.getName().replaceAll("^0+", "");
```

This will replace all 0's at the beginning of the `String` with `""`.
`^` means "begins with"
`+` means 1 or more of the preceding character or group, in this case `0`.

Comment: What about `0016.xls`

Comment: Only replaces the first 0. 0000016.xls turns out 000016.xls and not 16.xls. And 0000160.xls gets named 000160.xls

Comment: @user3082887 Welcome to SO.  Here, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

you need regex:

```
inputWorkbook.getName().replaceAll("^0*", "");
```

`^` means "begins with"

`*` means 0 or many

Comment: PS: It's 0 or more, and you simply repeated my answer, and it was originally incorrect.

Comment: Wasn't paying attention to when you updated, and removed my downvote when you fixed your code...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String string = "0000160.xls";
String[] parts = string.split("."); // split your string
int part1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]); // which make 160 because Integer
String part2 = parts[1];//xls
String result=Integer.toString(part1)+"."+part2; // combines both 160.xls
```

Comment: Why, but the result is fine

Comment: The ends do not always justify the means, especially in programming.  Just because something gives the correct answer, doesn't meant that it's a good way to go about getting said answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
String test = "00000160.xls";
int i = Integer.parseInt(test.substring(0,test.indexOf(".")));  
String fileName = i+".xls";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
String fileName = Integer.valueOf(inputWorkbook.getName().substring(0, 7)) + ".xls";
```

Only works, if your filename-pattern is like "[0-9]{8}.xls".